# Free shipping should not work after applying discount coupon and total less than $50?

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, free-shipping

I want to apply free shipping for subtotal more than $50 and it's working fine. but if customer applied any discount coupon then free shipping should not apply because grand total is less than $50. For now, Free shipping still applying because Subtotal is still greater than $50.

Can anyone help me how to remove free shipping if Grand total less than $50 after applying discount coupon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the `collectRates` method of `freeshipping`

For this copy `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping.php` in local folder with same directory combination.

and replace this condition ::

```
if (($request->getFreeShipping())
    || ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >=
        $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal'))
)
```

With

```
if (($request->getFreeShipping())
    || ($request->getPackageValueWithDiscount() >=
        $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal'))
)
```

Comment: after changing this code, free shipping method is not at all displaying even when cart total is more than $100. Can you please check this again.

Comment: replace `getBaseSubtotalInclTax()` with `getPackageValueWithDiscount()`

Comment: `getPackageValueWithDiscount` is working fine but if we are using any other extension Like DPD shipping method then it will affect module functionality ?

Comment: No. This will only change the freeshipping method.